# Adding related data through navigation property in EF Core 8

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

I would like to add some related data through a navigation property.

I have these classes:

```cs
[EntityTypeConfiguration(typeof(EmotionConfiguration))]
public class Emotion
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LocalizedEmotionInfo> LocalizedInfos { get; set; } = null!;
}

internal sealed class EmotionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Emotion>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Emotion> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        builder.HasMany(e => e.LocalizedInfos)
            .WithOne(e => e.Emotion)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.EmotionId);

        builder.Navigation(e => e.LocalizedInfos);
    }
}

[EntityTypeConfiguration(typeof(LocalizedEmotionInfoConfiguration))]
public class LocalizedEmotionInfo
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Lcid { get; set; } = null!;

    public Guid EmotionId { get; set; }

    public virtual Emotion Emotion { get; set; } = null!;
}

internal sealed class LocalizedEmotionInfoConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<LocalizedEmotionInfo>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<LocalizedEmotionInfo> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        builder.HasIndex(e => new { e.EmotionId, e.Lcid })
            .IsUnique();
    }
}
```

But when I try to add a `LocalizedEmotionInfo` through the navigation property, like

```cs
var localizedEmotionInfo = new LocalizedEmotionInfo()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Lcid = "en-EN",
    LocalizedName = "Anger",
    LocalizedDesciption = "Some emotion",
};

var emotion = await _context.Emotions
    .Where(e => e.Id == emotionId)
    .Include(e => e.LocalizedInfos)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

if (emotion is null)
{
    this._logger.LogWarning("Tried updating non existing emotion {Guid}", emotionId);

    return null;
}

emotion.LocalizedInfos.Add(localizedEmotionInfo);

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I get this error

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was 
expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or 
deleted since entities were loaded. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 
for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Update.Internal.NpgsqlModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyExceptionAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, Int32 commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Update.Internal.NpgsqlModificationCommandBatch.Consume(RelationalDataReader reader, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I use the newest version of

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0" />
```

and use the `IdentityDbContext` as a base class.

And yes I know that I can simply add the new object to the context directly, but I would like to understand why this does not work. Because I understood from the msdn docs that it should work out-of-the-box.

**Update:**

This is what the `ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView` is after the new object was added to the navigation property (There were 2 before, a third should be added)

```
Emotion {Id: 831d0e70-57be-4616-bf14-3b5a3f4b20d0} Unchanged
    Id: '831d0e70-57be-4616-bf14-3b5a3f4b20d0' PK
    Color: ''
    IsCoreEmotion: 'True'
    IsDeleted: 'False'
    Name: 'Anger'
  DefaultComposeParts: []
  LocalizedInfos: [{Id: 1153a315-079f-4a11-a0ce-4e84beb8e622}, {Id: 9b8badff-b9d8-49bc-aa65-9b4d4101e7bb}, <not found>]
  UserDefinedCompositions: []
LocalizedEmotionInfo {Id: 1153a315-079f-4a11-a0ce-4e84beb8e622} Unchanged
    Id: '1153a315-079f-4a11-a0ce-4e84beb8e622' PK
    EmotionId: '831d0e70-57be-4616-bf14-3b5a3f4b20d0' FK
    Lcid: 'fr-FR'
    LocalizedDesciption: 'string'
    LocalizedName: 'string'
  Emotion: {Id: 831d0e70-57be-4616-bf14-3b5a3f4b20d0}
LocalizedEmotionInfo {Id: 9b8badff-b9d8-49bc-aa65-9b4d4101e7bb} Unchanged
    Id: '9b8badff-b9d8-49bc-aa65-9b4d4101e7bb' PK
    EmotionId: '831d0e70-57be-4616-bf14-3b5a3f4b20d0' FK
    Lcid: 'de-DE'
    LocalizedDesciption: 'Wut is blöd'
    LocalizedName: 'Wut'
  Emotion: {Id: 831d0e70-57be-4616-bf14-3b5a3f4b20d0}
```

and this is the sql statement the entity framework send to the DB during the `SaveChangesAsync` call.

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@p4='?' (DbType = Guid), @p0='?' (DbType = Guid), @p1='?', @p2='?', @p3='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      UPDATE "LocalizedEmotionInfos" SET "EmotionId" = @p0, "Lcid" = @p1, "LocalizedDesciption" = @p2, "LocalizedName" = @p3
      WHERE "Id" = @p4;
```

So it looks like the Entity Framwork didn't registered the new entity as a new one, but only wanted to change a not existing one.

Comment: Please add the code for when the "localizedEmotionInfo" is populated.  For the one-to-many relationship and configuration, set this up on one side or the other, not both. (remove from one of the entity configurations.) Also, unrelated to the issue but more of an optimization with collection references (Emotion.LocalizedInfos) initialize this to `new List<LocalizedEmotionInfo>()` rather than `null!` and a protected setter. This ensures it is always ready to go, and prevents dangerous statements like using the setter to create/reference a new collection.

Comment: If it can help, I tried your code copying it in a new Console Application, and running, using PostgreSql 8.0.0 nuget package. No problems at all. But I didn't use ASP.NET Core Identity. Anyway, **you don't have to use ".Include..."** if you want to simply add a new element to the Collection, because, in every case, only this new one will be saved (added), being the existing ones included like "unchanged".

Comment: @StevePy I added the population of the `localizedEmotionInfo` variable (in the project, it is created by a mapper). I also removed the configuration on one side, but the error still happens.

Comment: @FabioCaruso Thanks I will later this week also try to reproduce the error in different settings

Comment: I believe there is something more about the entities that is not being put in the example. Are there any additional properties, navigation or otherwise in either Emotion or LocalizedEmotionInfo? Any values being populated by the DbContext on a SaveChanges override? Look into capturing the SQL that EF generates for the inserts/updates against the database (profiler/logging) and inspect that for clues for missing data . Eliminate values from the entity mappings, everything optional/nullable to work out which properties might be behind the error.

Comment: Also check the DbContext change tracker for any/all entities in an added or updated state. SaveChanges can end up attempting to persist other changes you might not be expecting to be persisted at this time, leading to errors from a poisoned DbContext.

Comment: @StevePy thanks for the tip with the database logging. I figured out that the EF didn't noticed the new object as a new entry, but as an existing one and wanted to just update the data

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The problem was that in

```cs
var localizedEmotionInfo = new LocalizedEmotionInfo()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Lcid = "en-EN",
    LocalizedName = "Anger",
    LocalizedDesciption = "Some emotion",
};
```

the `Id` (so primary key) was set to a non-default value. Which seamlingly lets the Entity Framework think that this entity corresponds to an existing row in the database.

If the `Id` property is set to `default` or not set at all then it works.

Comment: Ah, this is PostgreSQL, that may be a difference in behavior with Guid PKs, or something has possibly changed in EF Core with IDs and Identity. Normally there would be an opposite problem where devs would set an Id to a value on a new entity expecting it to associate to an existing row, and EF would attempt to insert, generating a new ID (if identity) or raising a unique constraint violation on the duplicate PK.  Curious to see that behavior may have changed!